# install qtcreator kit on raspberry pi 4b - 64 bit

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, qt, 64-bit

I've tries sudo apt install qtcreator and menu / preferences / add/remove software - search qtcreator, check qtcreator, apply

both seem to install qtcreator ok.  But it can't find any qt kit.

which qmake is in /usr/bin and is a softlink to qtchooser but when I Add it as a kit, it says

The qmake executable /usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake could not be added: qmake "/usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake" is not an executable.

is there something further I need to sudo apt install ?  qtcreator seems to have several libqt5*5 libraries that are pulled in as dependencies and are already there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The qtcreator package from `apt` only installs Qt Creator without any Qt installation. To use Qt Creator for development on Raspberry Pi, you must install Qt separately. I found [this guide](https://qengineering.eu/install-qt5-with-opencv-on-raspberry-pi-4.html) that explains how to install Qt 5 on Raspberry Pi through apt package manager.

Alternatively, you can [build Qt from source](https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_6_from_Git) (the link is specifically for building Qt 6 from source) but this might take a very long time if you're building it directly on the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I've found this works on latest (as of 2022/07/01) 32bit standard raspi os:   sudo apt install qtcreator qtbase5-dev qt5-qmake cmake libasound2-dev
    (asound is for alsa midi)